# Does sparkjava template automatically include the request

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spark-java

I have a verb that does this

```
get("/login", (req, res) -> {
        req.attribute("a", "message");
        req.session().attribute("message", "");
        return new ModelAndView(null, "");

    }, new PebbleTemplateEngine());
```

Will I automatically get to use request.a to return "message" in my template?
Or must I copy the request into map.